# how to do git merge the correct way

Tags: git, github

I have two branches : master and branch2.

They only differ on 1 line for a comment:

master has comment : //test 00

branch2 has comment: //test 99

assuming that i start off with branch2 and i merge into master, would that line be

//test 00 or //test 99 ? when i tried it out it git bash, it returned the message "Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy." but it did not actually show me the changes.

```
PS C:\Node\projects\n-5-10-workflow-test> git checkout branch2
 Switched to branch 'branch2'
PS C:\Node\projects\n-5-10-workflow-test> git status
 On branch branch2
 nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS C:\Node\projects\n-5-10-workflow-test> git remote show origin
 * remote origin
 Fetch URL: https://github.com/masterinex/workflow.git
 Push URL: https://github.com/masterinex/workflow.git
 HEAD branch: master
 Remote branches:
  branch2 tracked
  master tracked
 Local branch configured for 'git pull':
  master merges with remote master
 Local refs configured for 'git push':
  branch2 pushes to branch2 (fast-forwardable)
  master pushes to master (up to date)
PS C:\Node\projects\n-5-10-workflow-test> git status
 On branch branch2
 nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS C:\Node\projects\n-5-10-workflow-test> git branch -a
 * branch2
 master
 remotes/heroku/master
 remotes/origin/branch2
 remotes/origin/master
PS C:\Node\projects\n-5-10-workflow-test> git merge master
 Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
PS C:\Node\projects\n-5-10-workflow-test>
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Branches `master` and `branch2`] only differ on 1 line for a comment:
>
> master has comment : //test 00
>
> branch2 has comment: //test 99

This is ... not useless, but also not exactly use*ful* information.  When you're interested in what `git merge` will do, the contents of the tips of each branch are *not* the keys to the answer.  More precisely, they're necessary, but sorely insufficient.

First, remember that commits contain files.  I presume when you say "`master` has X and `branch2` has Y" you really mean: *All files in the tip commits identified by `master` and `branch2` respectively are identical, except for some file **F**, which has some line **L** whose text is different: that line reads `//test 00` in `master`, and `//test 99` in `branch2`.*

That is, if we were to draw the commit graph, it might look like this:

```
          o--o--X   <-- master
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--Y   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

(There are other possible shapes, but the output from `git merge` suggests it was much like this.  The name `HEAD` is attached to `branch2` because that is the one that you have checked-out.)

Here I've used `X` and `Y` to denote the actual hash IDs of the *tip commits* of branches `master` and `branch2`.  Because each commit contains the hash ID of its immediate parent commit(s), we can work backwards from the last commit on `master` to the previous commit on `master`, and from there to *its* previous commit, and so on.  We can also start at commit `Y` and move backwards.  When we move backwards, simultaneously, from *both* commits, we will eventually reach some joining-up point: commit `*`, rather than one of the round `o` commits.

The first such joining-up point is very special to `git merge`, because it is the *merge base*.  The merge base is the key to understanding what `git merge` is going to do.

**The goal of a merge is to combine work**, not simply to make two branches identical.  In order to *combine* the work done, Git has to find out *what the work was*.  The work consists of *all changes made since the common starting point*.  The merge base is that common starting point.

Git will now, in effect, run two separate `git diff` commands.  One will compare commit `*` to commit `X`, to see what "they"—whoever they are—did on branch `master`.  The other will compare commit `*` to commit `Y`, to see what *you* did on your branch, `branch2`.  That is:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-Y>   # what did we change, on branch2?
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-X>   # what did they change, on master?
```

Git then *combines* the two sets of changes and applies the combined changes to the contents of commit `*`.

Since you, in `branch2`, obviously did everything the same as what they, in `master`, did, *except* for the change to line *L* of file *F*, the combined changes will be the same except for this line.  The question is now: *who changed the line?*

Let's say that in `*`, the line reads `//test 00`.  Then *you* changed the line, so Git will take *your* change, and the result will be that line *L* of file *F* will read `//test 99`.

But let's say instead that in `*`, the line reads `//test 99`.  Then *they* changed the line, so Git will take *their* change, and the result will be that line *L* of file *F* will read `//test 00`.

Finally, it was possible that in `*`, the line read something else entirely.  In that case, both you and they changed the *same* line of the *same* file, but to two different things.  In that case, `git merge` will declare that there is a conflict, and will stop and leave a mess that you have to clean up.  Since that did not happen, obviously that was not the case.

Inspecting the file will tell you which change Git kept, and that in turn will tell you how the line looked in the merge base.  Or you could locate the merge base yourself, and inspect that version of that file in that particular commit.  But given what you have told us, it's not possible for us to predict which line went into the merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

when you do a **git merge** you are bringing the master branch to the actual one.

```
//on branch branch2
git merge master
```

all content from MASTER goes to BRANCH2

BRANCH2 <--------- MASTER

Answer (score 0):

Your merge has merged your local `master` branch *into* your local working branch (`branch2`). Because there were no conflicts, it is likely that the history of this line is as follows:

```
|
* (master)         // test 99
|\
| * (branch2)      // test 99
* | (master)       // test 00
|\|
| * (branch2)      // test 00
```

Meaning that the file on your current branch should contain the text `// test 00`.

It seems that this is your question, but a simple `grep '// test' <the file>` would answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question, *"assuming that I start off with `branch2` and I merge into `master`, would that line be "//test 00" or "//test 99"* :

If you are merging `branch2` into `master` and `branch2` has been branched from `master` then the answer is "//test 99".

But if that line of code has been modified in `master` from the original value of *"//test 00"* at that point in time when `branch2` was created, then you will have a merge conflict.

If `branch2` was created from another branch with no root back to `master` then expect a conflict.  But by default in git all branches lead back to the branch labeled `master`... unless there has been some funky branching history in that repo.